# Flash object scaling issue in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, flash, css, opera

it seems there's a bug in Opera on scaling Flash objects.
I need to scale a large div (wrapper) who has other div's inside, and also, some of them has Flash objects inside. So, when i scale the wrapper div with `-ms-transform:scale()` the wrapper div and the divs inside it scales as expected, except flash objects. They always stay at the `scale(1)`, and the page gets distorted. Has anyone ran into the same problem and have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: And this works fine in other browsers?  Is there a dedicated resize function in the Flash code or is it being scaled by the page?

Comment: It works fine in all other browsers, that uses webkit, MS, and MOZ transforms. The scaling of flash objects even work on IE9, FF3.5, FF3.6. Every browser, except opera, handles flash object resize. The flash itself doesn't have any resize/scale logic, and there will not be any, even if it would solve the problem for the current object. The problem is, that there may be other 3rd party flash objects in the page, and when zooming, they can't be handled from my side.

Comment: I have also found this, it appears to be an Opera thing they're not changing much, on Opera version 27 it still refuses to resize Object elements.